# Colors in Android

Tags: java, android, function, colors, return

I am using colors in Android but I don't know the format. 
Here's a working example in JAVA.

```
public Color getColor(int i) {
  switch (i%8) {
     case 0: return Color.blue;
     case 1: return Color.red;
     case 2: return Color.magenta;
     case 3: return Color.orange;
     case 4: return Color.pink;
     case 5: return Color.green;
     case 6: return Color.cyan;
     case 7: return new Color(250, 220, 100);
  }
  return (new Color((i*80)%255,(i*80)%255,(i*80)%255)) ;
```

}

How can I create this using Android. What I'm trying to do is return a color of eight possibilities.

Comment: what is the problem.?

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: I want to do it in Android, beacuase  this Java code doesn't work in Android

Comment: i guess Color class return integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getColor(int i) {
          switch (i%8) {
             case 0: return Color.BLUE;
             case 1: return Color.RED;
             case 2: return Color.MAGENTA;
             case 3: return Color.GRAY;
             case 4: return Color.YELLOW;
             case 5: return Color.GREEN;
             case 6: return Color.CYAN;
             case 7: return 993399;
          }

          Random rnd = new Random(); 
          int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
          return color;      
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of color constants are uppercase on an Android, and a color is an int value. So you should change the return type from Color to int. Second you should change the constants name to reflect Android. Third you should use `Color.makeColor` to get the color from integer values

```
public int getColor(int i) {
  switch (i%8) {
     case 0: return Color.BLUE;
     case 1: return Color.red;
     case 2: return Color.magenta;
     case 3: return Color.orange;
     case 4: return Color.pink;
     case 5: return Color.green;
     case 6: return Color.cyan;
     case 7: return Color.makeColor(250, 220, 100);
  }
  return Color.makeColor((i*80)%255,(i*80)%255,(i*80)%255)) ;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the android Color class. This class only provides a few pre-defined Colors, which you can find here under "Constants":
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Also you have to write your code case-sensitive. So it must be Color.BLUE instead of Color.blue.

If you want to define your own colors you have to do this in a xml file in the res/values folder. For example, create a new file "colors.xml". In this file you put your colors as described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="color_name">#ff003a</color>
</resources>
```

You can then use this color in your Java code:

```
Color color = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name);
return color;
```

Hope this helps.